# Selecting an object given a div name stored in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This is a simple question that hopefully has a similar simple answer to it as well.

If the **id** of a div selector is stored in a string, how can I select the div object dynamically.

This is what I currently do, and I am convinced that jQuery must have its own way of doing this:

```
<div id="boo">Some content...</div>

var divName = 'boo';
var divObj  = $('#' + divName);  // I really don't like the concatenation of '#'
```

Comment: That looks like the right way to me.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean the **id** of the div, which is actually different to the **name**, but what you've got there is accurate and not that intrusive. I'd stick with that.

Answer (score 2):

You could also make a simple helper function if you want to:

```
var $E = function( id ) {
    return jQuery('#' + id);
};
// usage:
$E('myElement').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really talking about ID, not name attribute, than mentione by you example is good way to do it, I don't see anything mad in this solution.

If you want to use name attribute than do it like this:

```
var divObj = $("div[name='"+ divName +"']");
```

But name attribute is usually used in form input fields.